# Knockout Template Binding item not defined

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I am binding data to a template using knockout.  The first template binds correctly, showing the image and other data elements correctly, however I get the following error and it does not bind to other templates after the first one.

> Message: Unable to process binding "attr: function(){return {src:imageUrl} }"
>
> Message: imageUrl is not defined

Here is the relevant part of the template:

```
<a href="#">
    <img data-bind="attr:{src: imageUrl}" width="263" height="262" alt="image description">
</a>
```

Here is how I call it:

```
<div class="panel-body" data-bind="template: {name: 'album-template', data: thisWeeksOne() }"></div>
```

This is an example of thisWeeksOne

[image]

I believe that this is a timing issue, but am not sure how to handle it.  Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Could you show the rest of your code? Or at least the contents of thisWeeksOne

Comment: What is thisWeeksOne? Is it function or observable?

Comment: thisWeeksOne is an observable, I posted a screenshot of it above.

Answer (score 0):

Error message you get is pretty straight forward

> Message: imageUrl is not defined

so imageUrl is missing in your $data.

I did simulate your error:

**HTML**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: imgs">
  <p data-bind="text: description"></p>
  <a href="#">
      <img data-bind="attr:{src: imageUrl}" width="100" height="100" alt="image description">
  </a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var model = {
    imgs: [{
        description: 'Phone',
        imageUrl: 'https://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_processed_/8/0/csm_u11_life_alphr_1c09ab3e96.jpg'
    }, {
   description: 'Car'
  }]
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

You can use if, to check whether property is undefined like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: imgs">
  <!-- ko if: $data.imageUrl -->
  <p data-bind="text: description"></p>
  <a href="#">
      <img data-bind="attr:{src: imageUrl}" width="100" height="100" alt="image description">
  </a>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dx2acfh/13/

Comment: It doesn't explain how imageUrl loads the first time and not the second..

Comment: Ofc it doesn't. He has error somewhere else in his code, that he didn't provide. I just showed, how he can handle missing property without getting exception.

Comment: ImageUrl is there, you can see it in the image I attached.  The image also shows up fine on the webpage, so the binding worked.

Comment: well, you have to share more of your code, because here I don.t see any problem